# Which SCM tool supports these features?

Tags: version-control, perforce

I am using Perforce for the past 5 years or so and am very comfortable with the features it provides.

Based on your experience of a SCM tool SVN, GIT, CVS, etc, can you please tell me what features from below list is supported by that SCM tool.

1. Command line equivalent(not a cutdown version) GUI functionality
2. Branching to maintain multiple versions
3. Every change is identifiable uniquely(automatic running numbers)
4. Plugin for eclipse
5. Plugin for bugzilla or any other similar bug tracking software
6. Plugin for Maven
7. Easy merging/good merge tool
8. Lower disk footprint
9. Fast and low memory requirement
10. Client and server both for Windows OS (if at all)

Answer (score 3):

You might want to investigate the following:

- [Subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org/)
- [Mercurial](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/)

Answer (score 2):

Check out this [List of revision control software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_revision_control_software). Get informed about the pros and cons of each system and then make a decision.

Also make sure to search SO for SCM questions.

Answer (score 1):

Any modern SCM will match your requirements.

Give a try to [Plastic SCM](http://www.plasticscm.com) (except for Maven, I think)